# How to cnfigure Fiddler to redirect traffic to a backend tomcat application over SSL

Tags: ssl, fiddler

I currently have the following setup:

IIS Web Server 8.5 with rewrite rules that redirect the user when trying to access the site that I have created to a backend tomcat server application on port 8445.

The client hits the application by accessing the web page as follows:

Client types https://ip_address/igst in the browser --> Web Server has rewrite rule to redirect all traffic with context root of /igst to a backend tomcat application on https://backend_app_hostname:8445...this works fine.

Here is what I'm trying to configure

I want the client to access https://web_server/igst from the browser --> have the web server redirect the request to fiddler which is installed on the backend application server, and have fiddler pass this request to the backend tomcat server on 8445 so that I can see the encrypted traffic from the client all the way to the backend.

What I have:

Client Browser ---> Web Server ---> Backend tomcat application

What I want to configure:

Client Browser ---> Web Server ---> Fiddler ---> Backend tomcat application

Any ideas on how to configure this successfully? I have never used fiddler before :(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you want Fiddler to be configured as a Reverse Proxy on the backend server. See http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/UseFiddlerAsReverseProxy for more details, but the gist of it is that you start Fiddler on the backend server and write a rule for it to forward inbound requests to another port.